# Ubuntu-SDK-IDE: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, lxd

In the case applications executed from the Ubuntu SDK IDE in a LXD container can not connect to the X Server, the X11 socket in /tmp/.X11-unix was probably deleted and the container can not access the X server anymore.

The socket might be removed by one of the containers while it is
booting, make sure lightdm (or any other login manager) is not
installed in the container:

```
# lxc exec <container> -- apt-cache policy lightdm
```

Also make sure the X11 server is not started with "-nolisten local":

```
# bash -c "for i in $(pidof Xorg); do xargs -0 echo < /proc/$i/cmdline; done"
```

Some older SDK images from the beta testing phase (before Aug. 25 2016) had lightdm installed and removed the X11 socket, please make sure the currently used image is not too old by recreating the container.

However if that is not an option debugging the container is the next step.
To figure out which container is removing the socket, do the following:

```
# lxc stop <container>
# touch /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
# lxc start <container>
```

Check if the touched file is gone, if yes the container has removed it.
The default SDK images should not remove that file, so most likely either a update or manually installed packages caused the problem.

If nothing helps, contact us (zbenjamin, bzoltan) on IRC freenode, #ubuntu-app-devel.

Comment: I installed the SDK beta in May or June, but never got it running properly. Now I have uninstalled (purged) the SDK beta and installed the official SDK and run into the "The X11 socket in /tmp/.X11-unix is missing, the application will most likely not run." problem which brought me here.

Comment: Is there a way to reinstall completely and start fresh? Or do I need to some other kind of trickery to reinstall X11 socket?